# grub can't launch Windows 10 after Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I looked at some of the other threads with similar issues but none were having the exact issue I have and, furthermore, I found none with a satisfactory answer. So I figured I'd post my own.

I recently got a new laptop, an ASUS Zenbook ux303LB, and immediately installed first Windows 10 (using the free upgrade that came with the computer; Windows 8 was pre-installed) and then Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using Unetbootin and a live USB (no optical drive).

It was a bit of a chore just working with the BIOS to boot from the USB, but did finally manage to do it. However, once I finished installing Ubuntu and rebooted, grub started giving me issues. First, it registers the Windows 10 partition as "Windows Vista," which is odd but not really an issue itself as far as I can tell (it also did this while I was partitioning my drive, with the default "Install alongside Windows" option registering as Windows Vista as well).

The full list of options grub presents when I boot to it is as follows:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test
Windows Vista (loader)
Windows Recovery Environment (loader)
```

Pressing 'e' to edit the "Windows Vista" command gives me this:

```
setparams 'Windows Vista (loader) (on /dev/sda3)'

insmod part_gpt
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,gpt3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  944CC9654CC9432A
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  944CC9654CC9432A
fi
chainloader +1
```

Attempting to launch Windows USING said "Windows Vista" command gives me a very vague (and frankly quite useless) error message that simply says `An error has occurred. Press ctrl+alt+delete to restart.`

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7mj5.png) I get from `sudo parted -l`.

Note that the partition "named" `Basic data partition` with the flag `msftdata` is the Windows 10 partition.

Fortunately, I can still boot into Windows if I modify the boot order in the BIOS to put the Windows Boot Manager ahead of the drive itself. However, it would be nice to be able to use grub to boot either Windows OR Ubuntu, and not have to modify the BIOS every time I want to switch.

Ideas? Any help would be much appreciated! If anyone wants any extra information, let me know.

EDIT: I also forgot to mention, I did try running boot repair. Unfortunately, it tells me the session is in legacy mode and boot repair cannot run. I believe this is because I have had to enable the `Launch CSM` option in my BIOS. Disabling this option prevents me from booting into grub/Ubuntu entirely, so it seems boot repair is out of the question? It seems odd that this should be the case, but when I disable `Launch CSM` the only boot option I can see is Windows Boot Manager.

Comment: Did you try leaving the CSM off (machine in UEFI mode) but just turning off secure boot?  That might let you boot the USB in UEFI mode.

Comment: Yea - I've had secure boot off throughout all of these things I'm trying. I had to do it in the first place to boot from the USB. But now my issue isn't booting from USB, I have Ubuntu installed on the computer and no USB connected.

In any case, ONLY with the CSM enabled do I see ANYthing but the Windows Boot Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You see only the Windows bootloader in UEFI mode bacause that's the only bootloader installed for UEFI mode, the grub sitting in the MBR is totally ignored.  Since the UEFI bootloaders are just files, you can copy them to where they're needed.  Boot Ubuntu (in CSM mode since that's all you can do), and install the packages:

```
apt-get install shim-signed grub-efi-amd64-signed
```

That should at least put copies of the bootloaders into the following locations:

```
/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed
/usr/lib/shim/shim.efi.signed
```

(You could ignore the shim.efi since you're running with secure boot off, but I'd set it up so it runs either way)
You can try running the grub-install, but it's probably not the UEFI grub2-common version, so do the following:
Make a mount point for the EFI partition in /boot/efi (assuming it's not there), and put that into your fstab (use your UUID, not the one below, or just use /dev/sda1).

```
sudo mkdir /boot/efi
UUID=7A11-7B8B                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults        0       1
```

Mount the Partition there:

```
sudo mount -tvfat /dev/sda1 /boot/efi
```

Copy the bootloaders into the hard disk's default, preserving the existing one (which is Windows')

```
sudo mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
sudo cp /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi-signed/grubx64.efi.signed /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi
sudo cp /usr/lib/shim/shim.efi.signed /boot/efi/EFI/bootx64.efi
```

Put a grub.cfg stub file into /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg.  This file just brings in the maintained grub.cfg from the /boot/grub location.  An example below (change the UUID and disk partition)

```
 search.fs_uuid 4e9797fa-2b51-4c8f-9a5c-37ee2cbf88ad root hd0,gpt4 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

This might be enough to actually boot (it is on a removable media like a USB).  Try to boot in UEFI mode choosing the hard disk entry.

The usual install will put the bootloaders into /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
and set up a nvram entry to run them. Copy the signed versions of grub and shim to /efi/EFI/ubuntu removing the ".signed" and the grub.cfg file as above.  Use efibootmgr to set up the entry.  At some point, you might want to clean out the old grub-pc and install the grub-efi-amd64 package, but the above should be enough to get you running.

Comment: `apt-get install` can't find the packages. Do I need to do `apt-get source` first? If so, where are they located? Also, thanks for the help. First time I've installed a Linux distribution myself.

Comment: Okay, figured it out. The steps you listed helped me add grub as a recognized EFI boot option, and from there I was able to run boot repair... which told me that I was not running a UEFI-compatible version of Linux and to install a 64-bit version instead - even though I explicitly selected the x64 version of Ubuntu in Unetbootin, it managed to install a 32-bit instead. Re-installing Ubuntu as x64 fixed all of my problems. 

Oh well, lesson learned I guess - troubleshoot from the ground up.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my comment above:

> Okay, figured it out. The steps you listed helped me add grub as a
>   recognized EFI boot option, and from there I was able to run boot
>   repair... which told me that I was not running a UEFI-compatible
>   version of Linux and to install a 64-bit version instead - even though
>   I explicitly selected the x64 version of Ubuntu in Unetbootin, it
>   managed to install a 32-bit instead. Re-installing Ubuntu as x64 fixed
>   all of my problems.
>
> Oh well, lesson learned I guess - troubleshoot from the ground up.

Such an easy fix that I never even considered, simply because I assumed Unetbootin did everything right (and I used it right).

Would suggest checking the same thing - that you did not install a 32-bit OS - to anyone else having issues with UEFI dual-booting Windows and Linux... 32-bit Linux distributions will not install UEFI-compatible versions of grub, since 32-bit architectures do not support EFI (evidently).